# Using pandas dataframe.query to find identical rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet with around 13 columns that will serve as an index file for some data ingestion process. One of the columns indicates whether the files being ingested are new files or have already been ingested before. (Yes or no).
In order to say whether a new file has been previously ingested, i need to check whether its values for three specific columns are identical to any other entry in the index file.

That is,

Suppose I've ingested file Data.xlsx, it has a file name, file path, access time and some other properties. I now need to check my index file to say if there are any other files that have an identical file name, file path and access time to this one.

My strategy so far is to write the index file into a dataframe using pandas. My intention then is to remove all other columns aside from filename, filepath and access time. Then add the data on my new ingested file, and check if it matches with any other rows.

I'm looking for help in whether this is the best way to do things and how I would execute this.

Thanks

Code wise, I'm trying to create this method:

```
def neworold(self):
    df = pd.read_excel(self.index_path)
    df.duplicated()
```

When I ingest files, it updates an index_data property of my submission object. This method would read the index data (currently, a list containing about 13 entries, representing the values in the different columns), read the excel index file path, and then output True if it has been repeated and false if it has not.

This value would then be appended onto a method for setting index_data and a method for writing the index data into the index file:

```
def update_index_sheet(self):
    wb = load_workbook(self.index_path)
    wb.active = 0
    for k in self.index_data:
        wb.active.append(k)
```

Comment: Please add some code and describe your attempts and what you have done to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

For a hypothetical DataFrame:

```
df
   access_time fn path
0            2  a    f
1            9  b    g
2            5  c    h
3            5  d    i
4            9  e    j
```

I would use a dictionary with the column names as keys as this is explicit about what value should match which column:

```
# in DataFrame
a = {'access_time': 2, 'fn': 'a', 'path': 'f'}
# not in DataFrame
b = {'access_time': 3, 'fn': 'a', 'path': 'f'}

def file_in_index(index, file_attrs):
    """Return True if all attributes of a file are found in a single row, otherwise False

    Parameters
    ----------
    index : pandas.DataFrame
        Your index DataFrame
    file_attrs: dict
        A dictionary of key:value pairs matching column_names:file_value

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        True if no matching rows are found
    """
    if index[index['access_time'].eq(file_attrs['access_time']) &
             index['fn'].eq(file_attrs['fn']) &
             index['path'].eq(file_attrs['path'])].empty:
        return False
    else:
        return True

file_in_index(df, a)
True
file_in_index(df, b)
False
```

This works by the search looking for all the criteria that you set out in a single row; if the search returns an empty DataFrame then no rows match all your criteria.